# Why do I get a warning error when I enter my admin panel?

Tags: php, warnings, opencart

I am new to PHP and `opencart` and really do not know how I should solve this.

When I am on the admin panel on my website, I get to see this:

> Warning: include(PAGES/error_pages/404.php): failed to open stream: No
>   such file or directory in
>   /www/opencart1/fifafinity/comfifafinity/adminpanel123456,.@/index.php
>   on line 123
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening 'PAGES/error_pages/404.php' for
>   inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/share/pear') in
>   /www/opencart1/fifafinity/comfifafinity/adminpanel123456,.@/index.php
>   on line 123

In my code, the lines around line 123 are as below:

```
                        switch($page) {
                            case "login":
                                include(PAGES."/login/login.php");
                            break;
                            default:
                                include(PAGES."/error_pages/404.php");
                            break;
                        }
```

More specifically line 123 is:

```
include(PAGES."/error_pages/404.php");
```

If anyone could help me, it would be amazing!

Comment: check that you have the files in the appropriate directory. Also check that you are receiving the value of PAGES

Comment: @EdwinAlex Hey, I do have pages/error_pages/404.php in my directory. What do you mean with the values? I am new to php and do not know much :/

Comment: You have defined "PAGES" as a constant variable. So, check whether you have assigned any value to the constant variable.

Comment: @EdwinAlex How and where  can I check this? Sorry, I'm a php starter.. .

Comment: Can u change your code to "pages/error_pages/404.php" and check?

Comment: @EdwinAlex I changed it to:               include(PAGES."pages/error_pages/404.php");, no result!

Comment: remove PAGES and see

Comment: @EdwinAlex Now when I enter the page I see: 404!

The page you're trying to view does not exist

Comment: Can u post share the folder structure?

Comment: Here you go: http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/4238 @EdwinAlex

Comment: @EdwinAlex Sorry I misread, his is the folder structure http://nl.tinypic.com/r/vy6uzt/9

Comment: I got, the same issues while update to latest version. That time I just open the system settings and simply save the same values again.. (check the system setting and other settings (User, api, location tools..))

Comment: that doesn't look like anything I've seen in any version of Opencart before.  You sure you're using Opencart?  If so, someone's mucked around with your core files.  This is especially dangerous since it's loading code you know nothing about that is not part of Opencart during your admin login process.  Be careful...